# pickling object in python prior to execution using decorator

Tags: python, pickle

am trying to build a decorator that can use later on to pickle any function prior to execution, but am getting the following error

```
PicklingError at /

Can't pickle <function wow at 0x105ff9488>: it's not the same object as apps.sandbox_app.tasks.wow
```

here is my decorator

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import base64
import pickle
from models import Task
from functools import wraps


def register(func):
    """ Decorate a function to print its arguments.
    """
    @wraps(func)
    def executable(*args, **kwargs):
        return store_task_to_model(func)

    def store_task_to_model(x):
        Task.objects.create(
            task = base64.b64encode(pickle.dumps(x)),
            status = 'P'
        ).save()

    return executable
```

here is the decorator registration

```
from dj_cron.task import register

@register
def wow():
    x = 2 * 3
    return x
```

and the actual calling of the function wow as following

call.py

```
wow()
```

any ideas how can i solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why pickling doesn't work, but your decorator never actually invokes the function, and returns another function, so the code in `wow` won't be run.

Comment: the above code would work if i replace this return store_task_to_model(func) with return store_task_to_model(func()) but that means the stored pickle would be executable object which i don't want..

Comment: Why do you need to pickle the function at all?  Usually the function is available because the same code is running wherever you unpickle the object.  What do you really need to do?

Comment: Am building a scheduler based on HTTP request services (whereby you place a request for a call back and it hit back a specific given url). The way i figured of doing this, is to provide a decorator for anyone using this code whereby they can wrap it around their function, then the decorator will store the function pickled in the database, schedule a call back with the service and HTTP requests dies and wait for a call back. This is to simulate a cron job like behavior or to be more accurate to simulate a queuing behavior

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store compiled bytecode?